# background-size: cover does not cover the whole scrollable page

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

I am trying to have an image as a background. Background image should cover whole scrollable page (width+height). And background image should not be fixed, it should also scroll.

Here is example html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is examle css:

```
html, body
{
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}

body:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: blue;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/392018/pexels-photo-392018.jpeg');
}

.content {
    height: 1800px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w6nvqgjr/12/)

When you look at JSFIDDLE snippet, blue background color should not be visible at all - it should be covered by background image.

Is there a way how to achieve it?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/392018/pexels-photo-392018.jpeg');
}

.content {
  height: 1800px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: why do it to the ``:after`` pseudo tag. Why not just to the ``body`` tag

Comment: i got it working like that. Do you want me to post as an answer

Comment: A blue color *isn't*  visible at all in the jsfiddle...

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Because I do some filtering with that - e.g. blur. But it is not related to the question so I did not include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `height:100%` and make it `min-height` instead. You can also simplify your code like this:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute; 
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/392018/pexels-photo-392018.jpeg');
}

.content {
  height: 1800px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: As I said at the beginning, I would like to have background image "not fixed", it should move when scrolling. Can it be done somehow?

Comment: That's it! Almost. Any chance to get it working with pseudo tag? Because of additional filtering (blur, etc.)

Comment: @TomC. yes sure :) am updating